# Redirecting PDF links from another domain using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have two domains, let's call them first.com and second.com

We have a directory in second.com called reports, where all our PDFs are located, but we would like to these same PDFs accessible from first.com as well.

Can we redirect let's say `first.com/reports/84839049.pdf` to `second.com/reports/84839049.pdf` using htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
`redirect /requested/url http://second.com/result/url`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

You may want to consider using mod_rewrite though, unless you asked for an .htaccess configuration specifically because you have no access to the server configuration and mod_rewrite is disabled or not loaded.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
http://webdesign.about.com/od/mod_rewrite/qt/site_redirects.htm

You'll need some grasp of regex for mod_rewrite, but it can make configuration of the redirects a lot faster than having to add a redirect for every file on your site(s).